# Simple Restful service with POST request results in HTTP 405 error: Method not allowed

Tags: java, rest

I have just started working in REST. Below is my complete source code. I have tried JSON type , even plain text(TEXT/PLAIN) type. Still getting

> HTTP 405 method not allowed.

**JerseyClient:**

```
package com.post;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientPost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Client client = Client.create();
  WebResource r = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/PostExample/rest/priya/metallica/post");
  String input = "{\"singer\":\"Metallica\",\"title\":\"Fade To Black\"}";
  ClientResponse resp = r.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).post(ClientResponse.class, input);
  if (resp.getStatus() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
             + resp.getStatus());
    }

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
}


    }
```

**Resource:**

```
package com.post;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/priya/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }
}
```

**POJO class:**

```
package com.post;

public class Track {

    private String singer;
    private String title;

    public String getSinger(){
        return singer;
    }
    public void setSinger(String singer){
        this.singer=singer;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;

    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title =title;
    }

}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PostExample</display-name>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
 <param-value>com.post</param-value>
 </init-param>

 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have tried with XMl format too by using corresponding annotation in pojo/resource/client but same HTTP 405 error occurring.

Comment: @vinS Everything here is needed to analyze the question.

Comment: Please be specific in asking question. Posting the entire code will not help anyone.

Comment: Sorry. while sending post request from Client(JerseyclientPost) to Rest resource(JSONservice) I am getting HTTP 405 error - Method not allowed.  I just tried to create a track(Pojo class) with data from client. I have tried JSON and Plain text MediaType for the type of request sent by client. But I get HTTP 405 ERROR. please let me know if you need any information on this issue

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Try out these steps to solve the above.

1. Change the consumes from text plain to JSON (@Consumes(MediaType.ApplicationJson))
2. In the rest client use below code to create a JSON POST Request use this code
   ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
          .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

   3. Try calling service from external rest client like postman and see it how 
      goes.
   4. Most important thing please implement interface serialiazable on bean named "Track"